# Play! 2 scala: Adding an error to a form in the controller code proper

Tags: scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I have some validation on input data which I really would prefer to handle in the controller code, because:

1. It only applies in very specific circumstances, so cluttering the `verifying` function in the form definition  would lower code cohesion.
2. It produces collateral results which I need to use elsewhere in the controller.

What's a clean way form producing a new `Form` like the one just bound with an additional (field or general) error message in the `success` branch of `Form.fold`?

To illustrate, I would like something like the (non-existent) `Form.withError` method I'm calling here:

```
val form= myForm.bindFromRequest
form.fold(
  errors => BadRequest(view(errors))
  {
    case(data, button) =>
      button match {
        case Some("save") =>
          val r= costlyFunction(data)
          if (r.isOk) {
            doSomethingWith(r)
            Ok(...)
          }
          else {
            val f= form.withError("my custom error")
            BadRequest(view(f))
          }
        case ...
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
val f= Form(form.mapping, form.data, 
  Seq(new play.api.data.FormError("error.key", "my error")), form.value)
```

Apologies for the noise -- leaving it here in case someone else gets stuck as I did.

Comment: slightly shorter: form.copy(errors = form.errors :+ new FormError("error.key", "my error")

Answer (score 2):

Shorter alternative:

`val f= form.withError("error.key", "my error")), form.value)`